# Change font style in pdf (evince)

Tags: pdf, evince

Is it possible to change the font style in Evince pdf viewer as we do in gedit and LibreOffice writer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the font is selected and set, when the pdf file is created. If the selected font is not available in your computer, when you want to display the pdf file, the viewer might select another font, that is as similar as possible.

Beyond that, I don't think *evince* can change font style. A word processing tool, for example *libreoffice* might be able to do it, depending on how the pdf file was created, but it is not convenient and I don't think this is what you want.